# Forcibly drawing power from a higher being, examples?

Tags: magic, humans

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples on how people might forcibly and unknowingly draw power from an energy source they don't realize is a higher being? The higher being itself just used to be a raw energy source which "powers" a planet, but with the birth of humans has started to develop a sentient mind. The higher being is only partially sentient at this point, so if there are repercussions from the higher being, they might not be conscious or intentional ones.

Comment: If you plug in your phone charger in some public building, where does the electric power come from? Sure, you can _guess_ that it comes from a powerplant, but how do you _know_ it doesn't come from a higher being? Isn't ignorance the best answer here?

Comment: Yes, a billion. Classic sci-fi premise

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic? Have you at least googled it? This SE is ill suited for questions that are open ended list type questions. You haven't provided any criteria for evaluating what answer or which answer would be correct, therefore I'm VTCing as POB.

Comment: Since this has been put on hold, maybe work out the rules of your magic system, come back and present them to see if the relationship makes sense? You can check out other question using the magic tag to get an idea of what makes a good question (...or not.) https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic

Answer (score 4):

Some possible examples:

- Drilling for oil (or natural gas) that happens to be secretions or in organs of the larger being.
- Tapping river flows for hydroelectric (or hydromechanical) power, where the river happens to be part of the larger being's circulatory or communications system.
- The larger being(s) relies on nomadic creatures to either communicate within itself, or to reproduce.  (Imagine arctic terns or seals or bison playing the role that bees do for plants.)  Humans hunt or pen in the nomadic creatures.

Comment: Everyone forgets that before oil companies caused global warming, they saved the whales! You used to get your lamp oil from drilling into whales...

Comment: The movie [Infini](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3327624/) is almost exactly that plot line in a sci-fi context.

Comment: @kingledion I thought you just had to put a wick in that little hole in the top; no wonder I had so much trouble getting my whales lit.

Answer (score 3):

World of Warcraft runs on this: planets capable of supporting intelligent life are actually unborn, but sentient "gods." World Trees capable of reaching its lifeblood with their roots, wells of that blood, or items infused with it are magically and powerfully transformed.

I'm working on a similar idea for my elemental world. As their names and lives are forgotten, the souls of the dead become part of an eldritch horror-type consciousness. It's tapped by both necromancers who have no idea what it is and arrogantly think they're controlling it, and eldritch warlocks who know enough to realize they can't comprehend what they've contacted. Needless to say, neither the necromancers nor the warlocks know exactly what the entity really is.

If you're working with a magic system, I'd say to just work their lack of knowledge into your system's rules: what your characters know affects what they can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for the planet itself, following Lovelock's [Gaia hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis):

> The Gaia hypothesis [...] proposes that living organisms interact with their inorganic surroundings on Earth to form a synergistic and self-regulating, complex system that helps to maintain and perpetuate the conditions for life on the planet.

Your statement that

> with the birth of humans has started to develop a sentient mind

already points in that direction.

The humans harvesting oil, coal, gas, geothermal energy from the ground are actually sucking energy from Gaia's big body.